# How to collect and map values of custom types of a record to a string

Tags: elm

How could I simplify the code of `display` more:

Here is my beginner code:

```
type Symbol = Cherry | Seven | Bar | Grapes

type alias Model =
  { one : Symbol
  , two : Symbol
  , three : Symbol
  }

-- VIEW
display1 : Model -> String
display1 model =
  case model.one of
    Cherry -> 
      "Cherry"
    Seven ->
      "Seven"
    Bar ->
      "Bar"
    Grapes ->
      "Grapes"

display2 : Model -> String
display2 model =
  case model.two of
    Cherry -> 
      "Cherry"
    Seven ->
      "Seven"
    Bar ->
      "Bar"
    Grapes ->
      "Grapes"

display3 : Model -> String
display3 model =
  case model.three of
    Cherry -> 
      "Cherry"
    Seven ->
      "Seven"
    Bar ->
      "Bar"
    Grapes ->
      "Grapes"

display : Model -> String
display model =
  display1(model) ++ " " ++ display2(model) ++ " " ++ display3(model)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `Symbol` type instead of the `Model` and have 1 function instead of 3:

```
type Symbol = Cherry | Seven | Bar | Grapes

type alias Model =
  { one : Symbol
  , two : Symbol
  , three : Symbol
  }

-- VIEW
display1 : Symbol -> String
display1 symbol =
  case symbol of
    Cherry -> 
      "Cherry"
    Seven ->
      "Seven"
    Bar ->
      "Bar"
    Grapes ->
      "Grapes"

display : Model -> String
display model =
  display1(model.one) ++ " " ++ display1(model.two) ++ " " ++ display1(model.three)
```

Comment: A better name for `display1` would be `symbolToString` and, if the items are of the same type you can also do `[model.one, model.two, model.three] |> List.map symbolToString |> String.join " "`